# Android application for Internet Tv Streaming

Tags: android, television

I want to develop android application for internet TV.I'm in initial stage of this application.
    I don't have any idea to do this.Is there any API or SDK available to develop my application.
    else give some idea to develop own android internet TV watching application.Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

If the OS your testing TV is an Android customized operating system, you can take it as an phone with big screen (tvapi, 213dp) without touch, sensor, radio... etc. support. Other thing is the same with the app designed to run on Android phone.

More specifically, if you develop for Android TV, you can reference from [here](http://developer.android.com/tv/index.html).

Comment: Is any api available...?

Comment: @VairavelRajendran If you ask the system api used in Android app, the link i given has provided the api reference. If you ask the api to retrieve content(media stream) to show, i don't have better solution.

Comment: I need like this,pass params to api ,that will return media streaming

Comment: @VairavelRajendran The Android MediaPlayer framework is you are looking for. You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/building-multimedia.html) training and [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)